# Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT - GIT

Tags: git, bitbucket, proxy

Ao tentar clonar um projeto do Bitbucket, esta retornando este erro.

Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

A configuração do proxy esta sendo feita desta maneira :

git config --global http.proxy "http://usuario:senha@proxy:porta"

também usando no https.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907140/git-returns-http-error-407-from-proxy-after-connect

Comment: @sant0will já tentei essas soluções e não funcionou.

Comment: Um [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/can-t-clone-or-pull-due-to-a-git-outbound-proxy-604537638.html) e essa [pergunta](https://superuser.com/questions/768015/still-getting-407-from-proxy-after-connect) que podem te ajudar :D